# KSoap-Android causing Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, eclipse, ksoap2, ksoap, android-ksoap2

I'm fairly new to Eclipse and Android.  I am trying to add the Ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar file to my Java Build Path libraries, which I am apparently able to do, but the auto-rebuild is immediately giving me that above error.  I have searched the forums and tried cleaning the project already, but that doesn't help.  I've also tried other assemblies, all the way down to 2.5.3.  No success.

I am running Eclipse version 3.5.2, Build M20100211-1343, Galileo Build.  I'm pretty much dead in the water until I can get this installed.  Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not followed the download instructions on the wiki correctly. Read the bold text on the page again.

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse

And download the latest version instead of an old one.